# Validate Facebook access token with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

What is the fastest and most efficient method for validating a Facebook access token? I know I could just use ajax to check if there is an error message when I request "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...", but if there isn't an error I will have to wait a few extra seconds for the query results to come back, which will add up if I want to validate the token frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use official way of doing things? Here's the request from FB's own video about security.

Request: https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token-to-check}&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}

Response: "data": { "app_id": {token-app-id}, "user_id": {token-user-id}, ... }

Link to an official video: https://www.facebook.com/FacebookforDevelopers/videos/10152795636318553/ (this url presented @26:00)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with facebook to see if the token is valid - no way around that. It is a token for their site afterall. Once you know the token is valid, I wouldn't keep checking the validity - just request whatever you want from facebook, if there is an error handle it. Also, facebook is generally pretty fast and under a second, so it isn't too bad for users.

And to directly answer your question, I like to use this code:

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            //they are logged in. Do your stuff. Check permissions too!
        }
    }
```